# Are there any known collisions for the SHA (1 & 2) family of hash functions?

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, sha-1, sha-2

Are there any known collisions for the hash functions SHA-1, SHA-224, SHA-256, SHA-384, and SHA-512?

By that, I mean are there known values of $a$ and $b$ where $F(a) = F(b)$ and $a ≠ b$?

Comment: meanwhile, a free start collision for sha-1 compress function was found. see [here](https://sites.google.com/site/itstheshappening/).

Comment: There is now a published collision for SHA1 at https://shattered.it/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the new attack on SHA-1 "SHAttered" and how does it work?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/44131/what-is-the-new-attack-on-sha-1-shattered-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: @kenorb that answers only a part of this question.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**This answer is now out of date as on Feb 23 2017, a collision for SHA-1 was found. See [What is the new attack on SHA-1 “SHAttered” and how does it work?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/44131/what-is-the-new-attack-on-sha-1-shattered-and-how-does-it-work)**

In short, no.

So, what is the current state of cryptanalysis with SHA-1 (for reference only as this question relates to SHA-2) and SHA-2? Bruce Schneier has declared [SHA-1 broken](http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2005/02/sha1_broken.html). That is because researchers found a way to break full SHA-1 in $2^{69}$ operations. Much less than the $2^{80}$ operations it should take to find a collision due to the [birthday paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).

As far as we know, the best available collision attacks on full round SHA-2 hash functions is still brute force $2^{n/2}$ (where $n$ is the bit length of the output).

Comment: That's why even after Keccak was selected as the winner of the SHA3 competition, NIST emphasized that it is not meant to replace SHA-2.

Comment: This answer is now out of date, because a SHA-1 collision has been published.

Answer (score 30):

First up, the following table should provide a nice comparison of the SHA algorithms and their status back in 2013, when I fist posted this answer:

> [image: Comparison of SHA functions]
>
> <sup>**[38]** The theoretical attack on SHA-1 refers to [“Freestart collision for full SHA-1”](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/967.pdf) (PDF) by Marc Stevens and Pierre Karpman and Thomas Peyrin, first published 8 October 2015.</sup>

Meanwhile – in 2017 – things have gotten worse related to SHA-1. Nowadays, **there are known collisions for SHA-1** and the graphic changed accordingly.

> [image: Comparison of SHA functions]

Related to SHA-1 being unsafe and (meanwhile) practically broken, the following two websites might also be of interest to you:

- ### Freestart Collisions  (theoretical, 2015)

  Website: [The SHAppening: freestart collisions for
  SHA-1](https://sites.google.com/site/itstheshappening/)
  <sup>([Mentioned by Ohad Cohen](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3049/are-there-any-known-collisions-for-the-sha-1-2-family-of-hash-functions#comment83358_3049))</sup>

  > This website contains latest news and background information regarding the SHA-1 freestart collision work from Marc Stevens (CWI, the Netherlands), Pierre Karpman (Inria, France and NTU Singapore) and Thomas Peyrin (NTU Singapore).
  >
  > You can find the latest version of our technical article here (currently under submission) and the corresponding press release here.
  >
  > …

and

- ### Full Collision (practical, 2017)

  Website: [SHA-1 has shattered.](https://shattered.it/)
  <sup>([mentioned by Dave L.](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3049/are-there-any-known-collisions-for-the-sha-1-2-family-of-hash-functions#comment100787_3049))</sup>

  > …
  >
  > It is now practically possible to craft two colliding PDF files and obtain a SHA-1 digital signature on the first PDF file which can also be abused as a valid signature on the second PDF file.
  >
  > …
  >
  > This result is the product of a long term collaboration between the Cryptology Group at Centrum Wiskunde & Informatica (CWI) - the national research institute for mathematics and computer science in the Netherlands - and the Google Research Security, Privacy and Anti-abuse Group.
  >
  > …

## TL;DR

The practical full collision linked above shows why you should **not** be using SHA-1 anymore. Instead, consider using safer alternatives… SHA-2, or the newer SHA-3!

So, to answer your question: ***yes, there are known collisions for SHA-1*** at the time of writing this (February 2017). But ***there are currently no known collisions for SHA-2*** (or SHA-3).